# Could not find a method sendMessage(View) in the activity class

Tags: java, methods, android-activity, sendmessage, illegalstateexception

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.myfirstapp;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.content.Intent;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.myfirstapp.MESSAGE";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    /** Called when the user clicks the Send button */
    public void sendMessage(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
        EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
        String message = editText.getText().toString();
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
        startActivity(intent);

    }
}
```

activitymain.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <EditText android:id="@+id/edit_message"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/edit_message"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/button_send"
        android:onClick="sendMessage" />
</LinearLayout>
```

DisplayMessageActivity.java

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class DisplayMessageActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Get the message from the intent
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

        // Create the text view
        TextView textView = new TextView(this);
        textView.setTextSize(40);
        textView.setText(message);

        // Set the text view as the activity layout
        setContentView(textView);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_display_message,
                    container, false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }

}
```

Error Log

```
04-10 01:37:00.460: W/dalvikvm(1650): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb3aaeba8)
04-10 01:37:00.520: E/AndroidRuntime(1650): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-10 01:37:00.520: E/AndroidRuntime(1650): Process: com.example.myfirstapp, PID: 1650
04-10 01:37:00.520: E/AndroidRuntime(1650): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method sendMessage(View) in the activity class com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity for onClick handler on view class android.widget.Button
04-10 01:37:00.520: E/AndroidRuntime(1650):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3810)
04-10 01:37:00.520: E/AndroidRuntime(1650):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
04-10 01:37:00.520: E/AndroidRuntime(1650):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
04-10 01:37:00.520: E/AndroidRuntime(1650):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
04-10 01:37:00.520: E/AndroidRuntime(1650):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
04-10 01:37:00.520: E/AndroidRuntime(1650):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
04-10 01:37:00.520: E/AndroidRuntime(1650):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
04-10 01:37:00.520: E/AndroidRuntime(1650):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-10 01:37:00.520: E/AndroidRuntime(1650):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
04-10 01:37:00.520: E/AndroidRuntime(1650):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
04-10 01:37:00.520: E/AndroidRuntime(1650):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
04-10 01:37:00.520: E/AndroidRuntime(1650):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-10 01:37:00.520: E/AndroidRuntime(1650): Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: sendMessage [class android.view.View]
04-10 01:37:00.520: E/AndroidRuntime(1650):     at java.lang.Class.getConstructorOrMethod(Class.java:472)
04-10 01:37:00.520: E/AndroidRuntime(1650):     at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:857)
04-10 01:37:00.520: E/AndroidRuntime(1650):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3803)
04-10 01:37:00.520: E/AndroidRuntime(1650):     ... 11 more
04-10 01:37:04.820: I/Process(1650): Sending signal. PID: 1650 SIG: 9
```

I've tried to look at other questions answered similar to mine, but I can't find an answer that seems to help my situation. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3):

I was struggling with a similar error following the [android tutorial](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html)

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.example.myfirstapp, PID: 18300
              java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method sendMessage (MainActivity)(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton with id 'button'
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.resolveMethod(AppCompatViewInflater.java:327)
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:284)
                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5197)
                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20909)
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5944)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
```

but in my case the WYSIWYG editor (IntelliJ w/Android Studio plugin) ended up populating the onClick property in activity_main.xml with some extra junk about MainActivity:

```
android:onClick="sendMessage (MainActivity)"
```

So I deleted **" (MainActivity)"** and it stopped crashing. I see this is different from your problem as your xml file already seems correct with **android:onClick="sendMessage"**.  But wanted to add it here for any others struggling with what I saw.  This was the closest post to the issue I was seeing.  I'm just getting started and this was killing me, so hope it helps someone else.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the onClick property in one of your Button tags:

```
    android:onClick="sendMessage" />
```

Just make sure you have a method sendMessage(View) in your Activity.

Comment: @acheronff3 No, it's not. The answer above is correct :)

Answer (score 0):

It is because you need to implement `implements android.view.View.OnClickListener` in your class, therefore add the correct imports i.e. `import android.view.View`.