# Android could not find method in Activity class

Tags: java, android

I'm following the instructions on the Android developers site for creating your first app. The first few platform tests worked fine for me, but it goes south when trying to use an intent to pass a message from one activity to another. Specifically, when I press the text field to enter input, the app immediately crashes (see intended behavior at https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html#DisplayMessage).

A problem that seems to be the same as mine was reported here over a year ago, with no satisfactory answer: [Could not find a method sendMessage(View) in the activity class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22979514/could-not-find-a-method-sendmessageview-in-the-activity-class?newreg=ecfd6288e3e94da4a36e2486dc9fada7)

A couple things I am fairly certain are *not* the problem:

- extends ActionBarActivity -- I know this is deprecated but it worked fine before this bug.
- hardcoded onClick in xml -- I have heard this is not best practice, but I doubt the official Android tutorial would instruct it if it didn't at least work.

My own basic and ill-informed diagnosis is that even though I wrote the method sendMessage(View view) in MyActivity.java, the runtime doesn't think it's there. I am lost as to why. Here's my code:

MyActivity.java:

```
package org.example.myfirstapp;


import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;


public class MyActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "org.example.myfirstapp.MESSAGE";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_my, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /** Called when the user clicks the Send button */
    public void sendMessage(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
        EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
        String message = editText.getText().toString();
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

activity_my.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<EditText android:id="@+id/edit_message"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:hint="@string/edit_message"
    android:onClick="sendMessage"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/button_send"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

DisplayMessageActivity.java:

```
package org.example.myfirstapp;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class DisplayMessageActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //get message from intent
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String message = intent.getStringExtra(MyActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
        //create text view
        TextView textView = new TextView(this);
        textView.setTextSize(40);
        textView.setText(message);
        //set text view as activity layout
        setContentView(textView);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Crash output:

```
    --------- beginning of crash
05-30 11:41:37.734  23198-23198/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: org.benwiley.myfirstapp, PID: 23198
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method sendMessage(View) in the activity class android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintContextWrapper for onClick handler on view class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText with id 'edit_message'
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4007)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
     Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: sendMessage [class android.view.View]
            at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:664)
            at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:643)
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4000)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Thanks so much in advance. I'm pretty lost. P.S. I am using API 22 with Build Tools 22.0.1.

Comment: The first illegal state exception says there is no onClick method named sendMessage() in your activity.

Comment: @Keshav1234 Yes but I don't see why. In MyActivity.java I include this:
`public void sendMessage(View view) {
        .....
    }`
And in activity_my.xml I include this:
`<EditText android:id="@+id/edit_message"
    . . . . .
    android:onClick="sendMessage"/>`

Comment: Add tthe following line in your xml and try:
 android:focusable="false"

Comment: @Keshav1234 OK, I just did that. It changed the text box from being focused in blue to being unfocused (unsurprising) but it still crashed when I clicked on it, with the same error log.

Comment: OMG I just figured it out... I stuck the onclick under EditText instead of Button on mistake. Classic. Thank you for trying to help me!

Answer (score 0):

i think you have many mistakes

activity_my.xml

```
<button
android:id="@+id/btnsend"
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
```

in MyActivity.java:

```
Button button = (Button).findViewById(R.id.btnsend);
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){ 
public void onClick(View v) {
 EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message); 
sendMessage(v);}
});
```

in AndroidManifest.xml  :

```
<activity 
android:name=".DisplayMessageActivity"
android:label="@string/title_activity_display_message">
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm not sure if it's what I need though.. first here https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/building-ui.html#Button it says that "Note: This button doesn't need the android:id attribute, because it won't be referenced from the activity code." It seems it should work without adding a listener to the Activity code (?). Second, my AndroidManifest.xml already looks like that, except instead of "@string/title_activity_display_message" the label is "MyMessage".

Comment: if it don't have ID you can't setOnClickListener.
in your project you didn't call method sendMessage.
sorry becasue my english is not very good :3

Comment: I understand that I can't setOnClickListener without an id, but my understanding was that this program shouldn't need to setOnClickListener and that activity_my.xml should call sendMessage. See my comment here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30549541/android-could-not-find-method-in-activity-class/30549762?noredirect=1#comment49172845_30549541

Comment: OMG I just figured it out... I stuck the onclick under EditText instead of Button on mistake. Classic. Thank you for trying to help me!

Comment: LOL :v you can find me on the facebook with 0949469777 (Evan Ngo) :3 if you have an orther problem ,i will help you if i can :D ...
;)

Answer (score 0):

While following the same tutorial I had made the same mistake in the `activity_my.xml` file, by putting the attribute `android:onClick="sendMessage"` in the `EditText` element.

It should be in the `Button` element, of course! The final `activity_my.xml` should look like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal">

 <EditText android:id="@+id/edit_message"
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:hint="@string/edit_message"/>

<Button
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/button_send"
android:onClick="sendMessage"/>

</LinearLayout>
```